# Text-align:center not aligning buttons in <nav> section

Tags: html, css, button, text-align

I'm not sure if this is a problem with this code or the surrounding code. As you can see, centering these buttons works perfectly when you run the code snippet.

```html
<nav id="navbar" style="text-align:center">
    <div class="div">
    <button class="navbutton" onclick="window.location.href='index.html'" style="background-color:rgb(0,255,0);
    border:none;
    color:white;
    padding:15px 32px;
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:16px;">Home</button>
    <button class="navbutton" onclick="window.location.href='reviews.php'" style="background-color:rgb(0,255,0);
    border:none;
    color:white;
    padding:15px 32px;
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:16px;">Leave a review</button>
    <button class="navbutton" onclick="window.location.href='recommendations.php'"style="background-color:rgb(0,255,0);
    border:none;
    color:white;
    padding:15px 32px;
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:16px;">Current reviews</button>
    <button class="navbutton" onclick="window.location.href='mailto:info.awolindustries@gmail.com'" target="_blank" style="background-color:rgb(0,255,0);
    border:none;
    color:white;
    padding:15px 32px;
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:16px;">Contact us</button>
    </div>
</nav>
```

For some reason, on my [website](https://www.wewillsellyoucrap.com) it just turns it into a pile of buttons.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a larger width for that container. In your css, change the class `div` from `width: 200px;` to `width: 100%;`

[image]

Comment: Hmm, I'm not quite sure what you mean. The only thing with a "width" element is the products. I changed that, but it didn't do anything.

Comment: Try this: Under your ```<nav>``` tag change this ```<div class="div">``` to this ```<div class="nav-buttons">```. Then add that class to your CSS: ```.nav-buttons { width: 100%; }```

Comment: Wait, you mean id, or are you talking about something else?

Answer (score 0):

It is because on your website you set fixed width of 200px to div element. Remove that and the buttons will go into one line;

Answer (score 0):

Try to keep code nice and tidy, styling on external file or at least seperated. 
When you click on "Leave the review" your navbar looks like you wish.

I copied code form "Leave the review" page:

```
<div class="div">
    <button class="navbutton" onclick="window.location.href='index.html'">Home</button>
    <button class="navbutton" onclick="window.location.href='reviews.php'">Leave a review</button>
    <button class="navbutton" onclick="window.location.href='recommendations.php'">Current reviews</button>
    <button class="navbutton" onclick="window.location.href='mailto:info.awolindustries@gmail.com'"
        target="_blank">Contact us</button>
</div>
```

Comment: That's what I had been doing anyway. For some reason, my hosting service won't let me connect more than one CSS document per HTML page, so by doing that, all the styling goes away, plus it doesn't really center it at all.

Comment: ok, I suggest keep all css in <style> tag, e.g you have tones of repeated lines. Give me 5 mi, I will post answer

Answer (score 0):

like I said before, keep code separated :)
Imagine, if you want different color to your menu, so you would have to change color in many places. Now you have all in one place and you can check other people syggestions about settings.

```
<nav id="navbar" style="text-align:center">
    <div class="div">
        <button class="navbutton" onclick="window.location.href='index.html'">Home</button>
        <button class="navbutton" onclick="window.location.href='reviews.php'">Leave a review</button>
        <button class="navbutton" onclick="window.location.href='recommendations.php'">Current reviews</button>
        <button class="navbutton" onclick="window.location.href='mailto:info.awolindustries@gmail.com'" target="_blank">Contact us</button>
    </div>
</nav>
<style>
    .navbutton {
  background-color:rgb(0,255,0);
    border:none;
    color:white;
    padding:15px 32px;
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:16px;
}
</style>
```

[Your website:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3Ygm.png)

Comment: I like your thinking, but it doesn't fix the centering issue :(

Comment: div {
    float: left;
    height: 250px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

Comment: just change width of your div. you set it to 200px. make it 100%.

Comment: Nothing happened when I changed that

Comment: and, delete float:left :) what about now?

Comment: Nope, still nothing

Comment: I added photo of you web, look at css, try everything in Inspector - F12
https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3Ygm.png